# Filtering custom posts by using checkboxes for taxonomy in an ajax loop always gives server 500 error

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, loop, ajax, javascript

I have been working on this for hours and can find no solution.

I have a website that uses a custom post type named 'Brands', which has a taxonomy named 'brand-categories'. At my client's request, I created a page where you could filter the brands, by allowing you to search for a brand and/or find all brands by their brand-category. It is done through ajax, so no page reload is necessary.

unfortunately, no matter what I do, I always get an error along the lines of

`GET https://darkm.co/womenschapter/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_ajax_filter_search&Brandcats%5B%5D=beauty 500 (Internal Server Error)`

when I attempt to search by taxonomy. I've run out of ideas. am I missing something?

This is my php

```
add_shortcode('WCAlphabeticalBrands', 'WCAlphabeticalFunc_Cleanse');
// Shortcode: [my_ajax_filter_search]
function my_ajax_filter_search_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); 
    my_ajax_filter_search_scripts(); // Added here

    // list taxonomies
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'brand', 'objects' );




    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ){
        echo $taxonomy->name;

        $terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name,
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach( $terms as $term ){
            echo "<li><label><input class='brandcatcheckboxes' type='checkbox' name='Brand-category-filter[]' value='{$term->slug}'/>{$term->name}</label></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }?>
    <div id="my-ajax-filter-search">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <div class="column-wrap">
                <div class="column">
                    <label for="year">Brand Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="BrandName">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
        <ul id="ajax_filter_search_results"></ul>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode ('my_ajax_filter_search', 'my_ajax_filter_search_shortcode');





function my_ajax_filter_search_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_ajax_filter_search', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). '/js/ajax.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'my_ajax_filter_search', 'ajax_url', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') );     
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_filter_search', 'my_ajax_filter_search_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_filter_search', 'my_ajax_filter_search_callback');

function my_ajax_filter_search_callback() {

    header("Content-Type: application/json");     
    /*
    $tax_query = array();
    if(isset($_POST['Brand-category-filter'])) {
        $BCat = $_POST['Brand-category-filter'];
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brand-category',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms' => $BCat
        ); 
    }
    */

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'brand',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    if(isset($_GET['title'])) {
        $search = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['title'] );
        $BCat = sanitize_text_field($_GET['Brand-category-filter']);
        $search_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'brand',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'brand-categories',
                    'terms' => $BCat[0],
                    'field' => 'slug'
                )

            ),'s' => $search
        ));
    } 
    else {
        $search_query = $args;
    }

    if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
        $result = array();
        while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
            $search_query->the_post();
            $result[] = array(
                "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                "content" => get_the_content(),
                "taxonomies" => get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'brand-categories'),
                "permalink" => get_permalink(),
            );
        }
        wp_reset_query();

        echo json_encode($result);

    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

And this is my javascript:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var mafs = jQuery("#my-ajax-filter-search"); 
    var mafsForm = mafs.find("form"); 
    var Brandcats = [];

    mafsForm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //console.log("form submitted");

        //console.log(mafsForm.find("#title").val());
        /*if(mafsForm.find("#year").val().length !== 0) {
            var BrandName = mafsForm.find("#year").val();
        }*/

        jQuery('.brandcatcheckboxes:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
            Brandcats.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(Brandcats);
        if(mafsForm.find("#BrandName").val().length !== 0) {
            var BrandName = mafsForm.find("#BrandName").val();
        }
        var data = {
            action : "my_ajax_filter_search",
            title : BrandName,
            Brandcats : Brandcats,
        }

        $.ajax({
        url : ajax_url,
        data : data,
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            mafs.find("ul").empty();
            if(response) {
                for(var i = 0 ;  i < response.length ; i++) {
                    //var html  = "<div>Result found</div>";
                     var html  = "<div>" + response[i].title + "</div>";
                     mafs.find("ul").append(html);
                }
            } else {
                var html  = "<li class='no-result'>No matching brands found. Try a different filter or search keyword</li>";
                mafs.find("ul").append(html);
            }
        } 
        });
});





});
```

Answer (score 0):

No any mistake in you code only just remove one line from you code.

Please remove first line from your code :

```
add_shortcode('WCAlphabeticalBrands', 'WCAlphabeticalFunc_Cleanse');
```